# Change git origin to a branch of my own

Tags: git, github

I cloned someone else's repo to my computer from github to try it out. I eventually made some changes to it (locally) that I do not want to commit to the original repo. Instead, I want to create my own fork of the project, apply the changes I made, then push it to my own repo. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add your own repo as a remote and simply push there :

```
git remote add myFork git://myforkUrl/project.git
git push myFork master
```

But if you want to work with github you should consider to fork from the github interface.

---

**Resources :**

- [GitHub - Fork a repo](http://help.github.com/fork-a-repo/)
- [git remote](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html)
- [git push](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html)

Comment: So I would fork the original project on GitHub, setup my own repo as a remote, then push to there? After that I can continue to grab changes from origin?

Comment: Exactly, this way you have two remotes, one for your repo the other one to update and keep track of changes in the official repo.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change what origin points to:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin git://newAddress/repo.git
git push origin master
```

Assuming you already have a bare repository already setup on git://newAddress/repo.git

Comment: -1: Though it will work, I think it is a bad idea to remove the "origin" - it means that you would not be able to get updates from upstream any more.

Comment: Yeah I agree, but I thought the OP was asking for it. I read too much into the question :)

Comment: @Jean: (a) you can always re-add (b) it _is_ the question

Comment: @sehe: If someone asks a question titled "Shoot myself in the foot" and states his intent in the question that he wants to test his gun, and someone replies "Take the gun, aim for your foot, and press the trigger" without mentioning either that he does not *need* to aim at his foot to test his gun, or that shooting yourself in the foot is not a good idea - I do not have any qualms downvoting that answer.

Comment: @Jean: [I see](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melodrama). You must have skipped past the (a) part of my answer

Comment: @sehe: If the OP knew enough about git to re-add the origin, then he would not have needed to ask that question in the first place.